# Stop Unity dash from following/linking file

Tags: unity, unity-dash, privacy

Once after I downloaded a file, it shows up in the **unity dash** as recently downloaded. Even after moving the file to another folder, the link on dash opens the file. 
Scarily even when I move the file into a folder which is listed in the **Privacy tool** as do not record the file link still opens from dash, even after rebooting. 
Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zeitgeist's "activity-log-manager" to prevent your system from scanning your Downloads folder.

#### 1. Install activity-log-manager

Open a Terminal (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install activity-log-manager
```

You'll be asked for your passwort. Type it in, confirm and proceed.

#### 2. Configurate activity logging

To open the activity-log-manager hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type **activity-log-manager**. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now configurate as you wish, for instance:
[image]
Everything in the given Folder (here "Downloads") won't be logged any longer.

Additionally it won't be shown under 'recently downloaded" in unity dash anymore.

Comment: ***The privacy tool in 12.04*** is the same as the settings shown there.